# jQuery create HTML from JSON String

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON-Object which includes following example entry:

```
description":"<div>- diversen Diskutanten- Moderiert vom gro\u00dfartigen PreibischDebatte, Gesprochenes, Kontroverses<div class="btn-group"><a class"btn" href=""><i class="icon-map-marker"><\/i><\/a><a class"btn" href=""><i class="icon-map-marker"><\/i><\/a><\/div><\/div>"
```

Now i am trying to add this html to another element in my code with:

```
$('#desc_text').empty();
$('#desc_text').html(event.description);
$('#description').modal('show');
```

The problem is that the html is not parsed as html, which I thought jquery `.html()` would do. I also tried with `append()`, but no change too.

Does anyone know how to parse this as html?

EDIT 2: The whole workflow, because it seems little confusing:

first I do:

```
$events = json_encode($func->getAllDates());
```

the function does:

```
public function getAllDates() {
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM dates ORDER BY start');
        $result = $this->db->mysql_fetch_all();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
            $result[$i]['description'] = html_entity_decode(utf8_encode($result[$i]['description']));
        }
print_r($result);
        return $result;
    }
```

Output of $result in function:

```
[6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [title] => Sabotage Debatte: Politik im Keller
            [start] => 2012-11-29 00:00:00
            [end] => 2012-11-29 00:00:00
            [allDay] => 1
            [url] => 
            [description] => <div>- diversen Diskutanten- Moderiert vom groÃŸartigen PreibischDebatte, Gesprochenes, Kontroverses<div class="btn-group"><a class"btn" href=""><i class="icon-map-marker"></i></a><a class"btn" href=""><i class="icon-map-marker"></i></a></div></div>
        )
```

EDIT:

As in comments said: The quoting seems the answer, but I don't quote by myself and just use php-functions. Maybe the way I do is the wrong way.

I got something like this from my database:

```
&amp;lt;div&amp;gt;- diversen Diskutanten- Moderiert vom großartigen PreibischDebatte, Gesprochenes, Kontroverses&amp;lt;div class=&amp;quot;btn-group&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a class&amp;quot;btn&amp;quot; href=&amp;quot;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;i class=&amp;quot;icon-map-marker&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a class&amp;quot;btn&amp;quot; href=&amp;quot;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;i class=&amp;quot;icon-map-marker&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;
```

then I use

```
html_entity_decode(utf8_encode($result[$i]['description']));
```

to turn it back and then i use json_encode to put it in json-format. Shouldn't do any of this functions a correct quoting?

I hope you get to the workflow...

Comment: Is that real JSON? It is not valid and I have no idea how you can get it working at all

Comment: After espaing the quotes it works: http://jsfiddle.net/paska/KMrxr/

Comment: Did you get this JSON from some other web service? If so you need to ask them to fix it because it is not valid.

Comment: if you have access to it, just make your backend echo html directly instead of JSON on the ajax call and just put the html where you want.

Comment: Edited the start-post, but the quoting thing it is, of course. Thanks.

Comment: But how are you producing the JSON?If you use `json_encode()`, the quotes will be properly handled. (see update to my answer)

Comment: They don't. The first example in my startpost is what I get after json_encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string has internal quotes which must be escaped. Additionally you have some faulty attributes like `class"btn"` which should be `class="btn"` After that, it will work fine.

```
// description with all internal double quotes escaped by \"
var event = {
    "description":"<div>- diversen Diskutanten- Moderiert vom gro\u00dfartigen PreibischDebatte, Gesprochenes, Kontroverses<div class=\"btn-group\"><a class=\"btn\" href=\"\"><i class=\"icon-map-marker\"><\/i><\/a><a class=\"btn\" href=\"\"><i class=\"icon-map-marker\"><\/i><\/a><\/div><\/div>"
    };
$('#desc_text').empty();
$('#desc_text').html(event.description);​
```

#### [Here is an example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLDZV/)

#### Update after OP comments:

Since you are retrieving this value and decoding the entities (which include the quotes), you must `json_encode()` it to produce properly escaped quotes.

```
json_encode(html_entity_decode(utf8_encode($result[$i]['description'])));
```

Or more likely, encode the entire array that this comes from:

```
json_encode($your_database_row_array);
```

Comment: Well, that's what I do and the end result is the string with with unescaped quotes.

Comment: Updated the first post again. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @movsky Using your exact array output from the function, I get correct JSON output. What is your PHP version? http://codepad.org/I8wUSsdZ

Comment: Wow. This is strange. I'm using PHP 5.3.8.

Comment: And how are you passing the JSON into your JavaScript? AJAX call or echo'd to output? If AJAX, do you use the correct `type: "json"`? Can you view the object in your JS console and does it look correct there? IOW, maybe your problem is client-side, not server side in PHP

Comment: I pass it with echo. And the output is the one you can see in the first post in the first code-block. I will try with AJAX. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try:

```
document.getElementById('desc_text').innerHTML = unescape( event.description);
```